# Reference same assembly from several projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have project with following folder structure:

```
ThirdParty
  v1
    Common.Dependency.dll

Solution
  Project A
  Project B
  Project C
```

All projects output copied to shared bin folder.

All projects are referencing Common.Dependency.dll from v1.

When new version of Common.Dependency.dll become available - v2.
As a newcomer I don't know that all projects are referencing same assembly from ThirdParty.
I'm just adding new version and update reference path in my project (Project A).

Now I don't know what assembly will be copied to solution output.
Is there any VS plugin, inspection or build stage tool addressing such issue?
I expect to see build fail in such situation.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the references on all 3 projects, else they simply continue to use the old dll. Meaning that, if 'Copy Local' is set to true, each project will copy the dll to the shared bin directory. That means that when project A references the v2 dll, and B and C reference v1 dll, and B or C is built after A, v1 dll is copied to the shared directory last, hereby overwriting v2 dll. Note you would only get build problems if the functions/classes in the new assembly have different signatures.

A couple of things you can do:

- v2 is a newer version of v1. So why do you still keep v1? If you just replace ThridParty/Common.Dependency.dll with the new v2, you sholdn't have to update anything at in the other projects since they'll automatically use it (unless a specific version is set - but even then you wouldn't risk having two versions of the same library)
- use NuGet if ThirdParty supports it. It is meant to deal with problems like this exactly, and updating to a newer version is just a couple of clicks in the package manager.